# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with large Matrix

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have **int K** as an input (K will be between 0 and 1000000 (one million), inclusive) and I would like then to create a matrix of integers with height and width 2 times longer than K number, plus 1 element more.

Example if  K=3, my matrix would be  matrix[3*2+1][3*2+1]=matrix[7][7]
        if  K=178754, my matrix would be matrix[357503][357503]

I got an **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space  exception in thread "main"**

```
int height;
int width;
int [][] matrix;

    public int getKthNumber(int N, int K, String direction) {

    this.height = (K * 2) + 1;
    this.width = (K * 2) + 1;

    ****matrix = new int[this.width][this.height];****   // error here
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this little problem since I believe that the whole other code is OK ??

Answer (score 4):

> my matrix would be matrix[357503][357503]

Yes .That's all enough to get out of memory. JVM tries to allocate memory for   `357503X357503` of integers, where as each integer carries 32 bits which resulting ~476GB almost.

What actually you are trying to do ?

Comment: the whole problem is here http://pastebin.com/qQBDYPXq so you can read more and get mu point

Comment: @Davd you don't need the actual array, you can do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

In a 32 bit system you can have up to 2GB . On a 64 bit system you can get more.

Command line flags are:

```
java -Xmx2g myprogram
```

But in your case it seems that this will not be enough, since 357503*357503*4/1024/1024/1024 (4 for bytes for integer) which is about 476G, so I think that you should rethink your solution.

Comment: I believe the maximum for the JVM is 2GB though in a 32 bits environment. But that may be operating system bound and specific to Windows environments.